# Which Amplify folders and files should or shouldn't be included in version control?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-amplify, aws-amplify-cli

Is it best practice to include the `amplify/` directory in version control? Much of the content within could vary for each developer, especially when each one is using their own hosting endpoint, authentication, API, and so on.

Is there a canonical list available that details which Amplify folders and files should or shouldn't be included in version control?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it best practice to include the amplify/ directory in version control?

Some files and folders should be included, while others shouldn't.

This is a good starting point:

| Folder | Add to Version Control |
| --- | --- |
| `amplify/backend` | Yes |
| `amplify/.config` | Yes |
| `amplify/mock-data` | No |
| `amplify/#current-cloud-backend` | No |

> Is there a canonical list available that details which Amplify folders and files should or shouldn't be included in version control?

Yes, AWS provide official [canonical guidance](https://docs.amplify.aws/cli/reference/files/) for developers to use.